# Locate ToolBar item on Screen

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a SWT application with an `ActionContributionItem` on a Form (yellow star on the top right).

[image]

Now I want to get the position of the `ToolBar` item, e.g. the `x` and `y` coordinates. So that I can move the mouse over it and perform a click event.

I can find the toolbar item in my test environment via:

```
if (o instanceof Form) {
    IContributionItem[] items = ((Form) o).getToolBarManager().getItems();
    for (IContributionItem i : items) {
        if (i instanceof ActionContributionItem) {
            System.err.println("found: " + i.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

However I have not found a way to get the position of the element. Do you have any idea?
If it would extend from `Control`, I could use `Control`'s `toDisplay()` method...

Comment: Do you really need to generate a click event, why not just call the action directly?

Comment: Because a "real" click event might trigger focus lost events which are crucial to us. Executing the action directly might behave differently on our system